# Joomla 3 module only a menu-page, not subpages

Tags: joomla, joomla-module, k2

How can i make a module only be loaded on a specific menuitem, but not on all subpages to this item.
I'm using Joomla 3.8.4, with K2. running on PHP7
Menu structure is:

- frontpage
- category 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3

When i am on Menu1 i want to show a fullpageslider.
Beneath this slider there is a Gavick News Pro Gk5, where i have a couple of k2-items listed.
When i click on these items i dont want to show the fullpageslider again that is being showed on the Item1-page

The URL on item1 is: example.com/category1/item1
The URL on the k2 items under item1 is: example.com/category1/item1/k2category1/k2itemalias

Im thinking of a solution where i templateoverride the item1-page, where i include the existence of the moduleposition only to be inside that, so that the subitems have a different layout, but im looking for a solution directly in Joomla.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Regular Lab's Advanced Module Manager.  You can set multiple criteria so assign to menu item but exclude showing on a specific type like K2 item.

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in this particular case both the item1 and subitems belong to different categories but still in k2.

Comment: Are they all K2 items versus K2 category pages?  In the Pro version, you also differentiate based upon K2 tags, meta info, etc.  Or it also allows for custom PHP rules.